# Does a Python threading.Condition.wait() suspend execution immediately?

Tags: python, multithreading, suspend, condition-variable

If I call `wait()` on a python condition variable, does the calling thread suspend execution and yield or does it keep blocking until the next context switch?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the implementation. The weird CPython threads probably don't, but that is just a guess from a vague memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread does yield. This yielding is due to the implementation of [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) or the equivalent suspension mechanism in in [`PyThread_acquire_lock`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d5b274a0b0a5/Python/thread_pthread.h#l423). Since the condition variable is implemented using the system call interface, and Python uses native threading, the operating system scheduler is responsible for switching to another thread.

Additionally, the [GIL is released](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d5b274a0b0a5/Modules/threadmodule.c#l51) before calling this deep into Python's internals. Finally the last piece of the puzzle is the call to acquire the lock in [`threading.Condition.wait`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d5b274a0b0a5/Lib/threading.py#l244).

Answer (score 1):

> The wait() method releases the lock, and then blocks until it is
>   awakened by a notify() or notifyAll() call for the same condition
>   variable in another thread. Once awakened, it re-acquires the lock and
>   returns. It is also possible to specify a timeout.

It blocks until the condition is notified.

Comment: Believe it or not i actually tried reading the manual first. If it "blocks" execution, why shouldnt i just use a spinlock instead?

Comment: A thread waiting on a spinlock burns cpu whereas a thread waiting on a condition does not burn cpu. Spinlocks are useful for cases where the lock is hold and released rapidly. Conditions are useful for cases where we don't know how long we will wait.